# Null.SetNull method in DotNetNuke/VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke

I was looking at some old code in DotNetNuke 4.x/VB.Net and couldn't make anything meaningful out of the following code. I know SetNull method is not part of VB.Net.

What is this code trying to do when Null.SetNull(ExamTrackerId) is called?

```
        Private ExamTrackerId As Integer

        ' Determine ItemId
        If Not (Request.Params("ExamTrackerID") Is Nothing) Then
            ExamTrackerId = Int32.Parse(Request.Params("ExamTrackerID"))
        Else
            ExamTrackerId = Convert.ToInt32(Null.SetNull(ExamTrackerId))
        End If
```

Comment: Are you using DotNetNuke?  DNN has (or had, it may be deprecated) a module and method by the name `Null.SetNull`

Comment: Yes. Its still there under DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities. But what does it do?

Comment: I found the answer. This method returns a -1 if the value of integer parameter is DBNull.Value, else return the actual integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a VB.Net language method but a custom method in DotNetNuke.dll.

Also, in DNN 7.00.04, there is no method called SetNull that takes an integer parameter, but there is a similar method  called SetNullInteger that takes an integer object, and it **returns a -1 if the Integer type passed to this method is having a value of DBNull.Value.**.

The method SetNull that exists in DNN 7.00.04 takes two parameters, and not one, as may have been the case in older versions of DNN.

So the correct code, it seems, in DNN 7.00.04 would be as below.

```
       Private ExamTrackerId As Integer

    ' Determine ItemId
    If Not (Request.Params("ExamTrackerID") Is Nothing) Then
        ExamTrackerId = Int32.Parse(Request.Params("ExamTrackerID"))
    Else
        ExamTrackerId = Convert.ToInt32(DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Null.SetNullInteger(ExamTrackerId))
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Null` class is not part of the .NET framework but part of the `DotNetNuke` library. I'm not familiar with this library but looking at the (C#) [source](http://code.google.com/p/cs-dotnetnuke/source/browse/trunk/CS_Library/DotNetNuke/Common/Utilities/Null.cs?r=24), it seems that the `Null.SetNull` method checks whether or not the input parameter (`ExamTrackerId`) is null within the database and, if so, it returns a value of the input type. Your code simply converts that return value into an `Int32` type.

It's a simple utility class so you could perform this check on your own but because .NET `null` is *not* the same as the `DBNull` type, it seems it's just there to make it less likely for you to accidentally perform an incorrect null check.

(I don't know if the link to the source code is outdated or if your code is incomplete but there doesn't seem to be a `SetNull` overload that takes just one `object` type).

Comment: It seems the original method accepting an Integer parameter under DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Null class is no more there. It returns a -1 if the parameter value is DBNull.Value. I added some extra part under UPDATE in my post.

Comment: Regardless, it's still doing the same thing but instead of having a single method that detects the type passed in, it shifts the call to the developer. If you know you're passing an integer, you can call the `SetNullInteger` method.